# Creating a custom dropdown list

Tags: android, android-layout

Just wondering how can I create something like this or does Android have this component already.

I will be using android xml layouts

[image]

When the user starts to type in the search this will show this dropdown list.

I have a few ideas.
Could I create a bottomSheet that can open from the top below the search bar.
Create a dialog fragment that opens below the search bar.
Create some custom dropdown list.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: One way would be to create a RecyclerView that is hidden when it has no items. Then just make sure it is on top of the rest of the view hierarchy, but below the search bar.

There are many open source libs that do something similar. You can take a look at android arsenal for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are correct. The recyclerview will be positioned below the search bar.